# How to get SQL Server variable limit in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a SQL Server table `Workers` and it has a column `Name` which is of datatype `nvarchar(20)`.

I am using an ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

In my project, I want to limit user input to 20 characters (limit of my `Name` column).

How can I get this data through C# code and use it?

EDIT
The solution I need is a C# code that gives me the 20(limit of my `Name` column) so I can dynamically use it as a validation data. By that, If I change this limit on my database it will automatically use the updated data so I won't go to my input and manually change it for new limit.

My table will be a c# class by EntityFramework so I will have a class named
`Workers` and `Name` as a property of it. I am looking for the limit of this property.

Comment: You can start with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute. But you give no information about your frontend.

Comment: This is a application , not an SQL issue; this would be part of input validation and you can either check the length of the string input or truncate the string. Also, `name` is not a good SQL field name

Comment: @PeterSmith For retrieving the info he needs SQL can be used, so I am not sure if it is only an application question. I agree on the name issue, though this is subject to opinions off course

Comment: @GuidoG A better solution is to use `nvarchar(MAX)` and also have proper client-side validation as a matter of course

Comment: @PeterSmith I strongly dissagree there, when there is only 20 characters allowed then the database must have nvarchar(20), when the client side can also restrict this that is a nice to have, but the database rules in every case.

Answer (score 1):

All this information is stored in the [SQL Server system catalog views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/catalog-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) in the `sys` schema.

You can e.g. get the max length of a particular column like this:

```
SELECT
    c.Name, c.max_length
FROM
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN
    sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE
    t.Name = 'Workers'
    AND c.Name = 'Name'
```

Answer (score -1):

Value is a reserved SQL word,so add [] to it.